# How can I mix string and JSX in react properties?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have JSX code like this:

```
<Item cate="capital" parm={"11"+{<span>.55</span>}} small="Feb" />
```

I think there's nothing wrong but my browser keeps telling me "Unexpected token".

how can I fix it?

Comment: Pass your string as another prop, it won't work the way you're doing

Comment: I added another prop, everything works fine now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way of doing it:
Pass it to your item component:

```
<Item cate="capital" parm={<span>.55</span>}
small="Feb"
addToParm="11" />
```

And just use it in your Item component:

```
<div>
    {this.props.addToParm}
    {this.props.parm}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ES6 template, try this:

```
<Item cate="capital" parm={`11${<span>.55</span>}`} small="Feb" />
```

[read more about ES6 template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)